# how to change correct Image path in Laravel Voyager

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, voyager

I am facing image path problem in my Laravel Voyager admin panel.

User image is shown correctly. Here is an image with image path

[image]

But other images is not shown correctly. Here is an image with image path

[image]

If I change the image path from `inspect element` then that image is shown correctly.
[image]

So my question is where to change the image path for showing correct image in Voyager admin panel ?

Image upload in `/storage` folder. Here is the `config/filesystem.php`

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path(''),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
    ],

],
```

Anybody help please ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to update the APP_URL in .env File

```
APP_URL = "http://gotravelsglobal.com/travel/public"
```